# mod-rewrite Regex RewriteRule depending on number of virtual folders

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do a rewrite depending on the number of virtual folders and using the foldernames as variables.

So using

```
RewriteBase /foo/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*).html$ date.php?country=$1&city=$2&date=$3 [NC]
```

for

`example.com/usa/chicago/09072015/dates-to-party.html`

gives me what i want.

But i don't get it working for

```
RewriteBase /foo/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*).html$ city.php?country=$1&city=$2 [NC]
```

`example.com/usa/chicago/locations-to-party.html`

I want to rewrite to city.php if there are two virtual folders (/usa/chicgao/09072015/.index.html) and to date.php if there are three (/usa/chicgao/09072015/index.html)

Comment: Why are you using `RewriteBase /foo/ when `/foo/` is not in your URLs?

Comment: What do you mean by "i don't get it working"?

Comment: i put the date.php and city.php in that folder to receive the variables.

Comment: @arkascha I want to rewrite to city.php if there are two virtual folders (_/usa/chicgao/09072015/.index.html_) and to date.php if there are three (_/usa/chicgao/09072015/index.html_)

Comment: Sure, but what does "i don't get it working" mean? Does no rewriting occur? Or is the rewriting wrong? Does the other rule still work or not? Does the universe implode? See, we cannot _guess_ what happens on your side. You have to tell us. Tell us in a _precise_ manner what you observe.

Comment: @arkascha In all cases it is rewritten to city.php instead of 3-folder->date.php 2-folder->city.php

Comment: Maybe you have the wrong order of rules? Always from more specific to more complex. It would help if you post your whole rule block as it is in the question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tweak your regex and must avoid using `.*`:

```
RewriteBase /foo/

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/[^./]+\.html$ date.php?country=$1&city=$2&date=$3 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/[^./]+\.html$ city.php?country=$1&city=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

`[^./]+` will match anything that is not a DOT or slash thus it will avoid the matching `date` URL.

Also better not to capture a value that you don't need in target.

Comment: Thanks a lot, all is working correctly now! Thanks to @arkascha for helping to ask my question more precise!